# Using the magnetic field in Android

Tags: android, rotation, sensors, compass-geolocation, axes

So I'm writing an application to see if the device has rotated 360 degrees. The way I do this is using the Accelerometer sensor combined with the Magnetic field sensor. From this method I get three values of the X, Y and Z axes, but how can I use these to calculate where North is?

I already did some testing: When I point one of the axes north, I the value of it turns approximately 0.0, but when I point it south, it also shows me 0.0 and different values per axe when I point it east or west (For X: somewhat around -3.1 east)

Comment: Ok, I think I'm on to something here, which in my case will work for me. I will just use the raw value of the X variable of my vector, because it just tells me the horizontal difference between the (magnetical) north pole and my phone's orientation. Because I use this value relatively (I just compare the two value's) this works for me. Tomorrow I'm going to do some tests with my theory and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I did some tests today and my solution worked for me, to just take the X value. This works for me because I only have to use it relatively (compare two values). For more information, look at the comment on my question or take look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) article.